# CGRect with an angle

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a line, which is a sprite made by using this code

```
CGPoint diff = ccpSub(startLocation, endLocation);
float rads = atan2f( diff.y, diff.x);
float degs = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rads);
float dist = ccpDistance(endLocation, startLocation);
CCSprite *line = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"line.png"];
[line setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.0f, 0.5f)];
[line setPosition:endLocation];
[line setScaleX:dist / line.boundingBox.size.width];
[line setRotation: degs];

line.tag = 1;
[_lines addObject:line];
[self addChild:line];
```

Now in my collision detection code I use the following code to create a CGRect:

```
        CGRect lineRect = CGRectMake(
        line.position.x - (line.contentSize.width/2), 
        line.position.y - (line.contentSize.height/2), 
        line.contentSize.width, 
        line.contentSize.height);
```

This of course is faulty because the line is made using an angle.

I'm trying to compare a rectangle, a square sprite, with this rectangle.
The idea is that a character is moving and the player can draw a line, if the character hits the line it's bounces of in the opposite direction.

I have the angle, the x&y position of one side of the line and the length of the line.
How do I get the other x&y position of the other side of the line?

Hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to test for collision? 2 Line segments? A line segment and a rectangle? A line segment and a polygon? please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, questing updated: 
I'm trying to compare a rectangle, a square sprite, with this rectangle. The idea is that a character is moving and the player can draw a line, if the character hits the line it's bounces of in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to know if I understand you correctly, but when you say "...the other x&y position of the other side of the line," I'm assuming you meant what is the coordinates of the  opposite endpoint of the line.

If so, I believe the actual formula you may be looking for is:

1. {x1, y1} = starting point that you already have
2. {x2, y2] = point you're looking to find

   - x2 = x1 + (distance * cosA)
   - y2 = y1 + (distance * sinA)

But as I mentioned earlier, I'm a little unsure whether this would give you exactly what you needed.  If you're actually looking for the points of the vertices of the opposite side of the bounding box for the Line.png, then perhaps you could still use that formula, but change the degrees by 90 to determine the coordinates offset from the x&y that you already know.

Anyway, I hope that at least helps put you in a helpful direction.

Comment: My apologies for my late response, was away for a few days.

Your formula is correct! I've tested it on paper.

But how do I check if my sprite (a square) has hit this line?
CGRectMake only accepts one set of coordinates.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: That's a good question on the best method for collision detection.  I'm struggling with that one myself.  It really seems to be determined by the types of objects you're using.  I'm not the best person to answer that question.  I'm writing my own, because I couldn't seem to locate an all inclusive solution to that question.  Your question here was how to locate an x & y given an existing point, distance, and angle, which I thought I might be able to help with.  I wish you luck on the other part though!

Comment: You're absolutely right, you answered my original question. I will start a new question about the collision.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look up the documentation for `CGRectApplyAffineTransform`, `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and possibly `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`.