# Collision detection on diagonal lines in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I'm working on a small iPhone/iPad game with the Cocos2d framework. Basically the idea of the game is very simple, there a ball which is moving at a certain speed. The user can draw a line so that the ball bounces in the opposite direction.

Now I've already have the ball moving and the user can draw a line also. (When he draw a line it becomes a member of an array and dissapears a few seconds later.)

But the question is how to detect a collision between the ball and a line? The line doesn't need to be horizontal or vertical, it can be diagonal also. It all depends on how the user draws this line.

I've the coordinates of the line: see the answer to my previous question: [CGRect with an angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230090/cgrect-with-an-angle)

Can you guys point in me right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box2d to detect collisions. Actually, if your ball and these lines will have bodies in b2World, you will be able not to check collisions by yourself. All changes, bounces, etc. physics will done for you. You will only have to synchronize object's view position (also you can synchronize angle) according to the position of it's body in physical world.

Comment: Hmmm I've just looked into a few examples of box2d and it looks promising. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/7261/monkey-jump
http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pixel perfect collision so when ball and line collide it is not check the rect but it check the pixel collision...

in this forum you got that you want..

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18522/page/3